# R Error: cannot allocate vector of size 7.1 Mb

Tags: r, memory, vector

I am loading methylation dataset of 102 cases. Previously I can run it in minfi or ChAMP multiple times, but now out of sudden there is memory issue:

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 7.1 Mb
```

I am running Rstudio with R version 4.1.2 on windows 10 64-bit, with 32GB RAM!!!
But when I run:

```
memory.size(max = TRUE)
[1] 3326.19
```

When I try to set memory size:

```
memory.limit(size=4096)
Error in memory.limit(size = 4096) : 
  don't be silly!: your machine has a 4Gb address limit

> version
               _                           
platform       i386-w64-mingw32            
arch           i386                        
os             mingw32                     
system         i386, mingw32               
status                                     
major          4                           
minor          1.2                         
year           2021                        
month          11                          
day            01                          
svn rev        81115                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
nickname       Bird Hippie
```

How come the maximum memory is only around 3GB!!! I have got 32GB RAM!!! R seems to be treating my system as 32 bit???

And when this memory problem suddenly occurs with the SAME dataset that is able to run with no problem previously for multiple times!!!

Please help!! Thanks!!!

Comment: You are running 32-bit R. You can tell because it says `mingw32` and `i386` in the output. 64-bit R would say something like `x86_64`. Just download and install 64-bit R.

Comment: And perhaps uninstall the 32-bit R so you don't get this problem again. !!!!